# Why my code keep getting java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified?

Tags: eclipse, ms-access, jdbc-odbc

can someone help me to let my database connected to java.
I've been trying this for hours but i still got this exception : "java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified?"

```
public Connector() {
      Connection con;
      Statement st;
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=Database.mdb");
        st = con.createStatement(1004, 1008);
    } catch (Exception e) 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Here's the exception that i got:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Have your code display the value returned by `System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")` and [edit] your question to show us what it says.

Comment: well i have tried it and it returns 64 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Java code is running under a 64-bit JVM (Java Virtual Machine) and trying to use the older "Jet" ODBC driver `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)`. That won't work because the older "Jet" driver is only available to 32-bit applications. You either need to

1. Run your Java program under a 32-bit JVM, or
2. Download and install the 64-bit version of the newer "Access Database Engine ('ACE')" from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255) and then use the ODBC Driver name `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)` when running your code under a 64-bit JVM.

Also, remember that the JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from Java 8 so continuing to use it is not very "future-friendly". For an alternative, see

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)